# Trying to sum arrays that overlap by grabbing data from a table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

my issue is hard to explain so I'm going to give you an example.
Let the sample arrays be:

`array1: 1,2,0,4`

`array2: 0,0,1,0`

`array3: 0,1,6,2`

I have these numbers separated by cell and not comma, but that doesn't matter.

Next step is: I type (as text, not formula) array1 + array2 in a column, and I want to get the result.
**So first example:**
`1| array1 + array2`

would give:

`1| 1 (array1 1st value) + 0 (array2 1st value) = 1`

`2| 2 (array1 2nd value) + 0 (array2 2nd value) = 2`

`3| 0 (arra1 3rd value) + 1 (array2 3rd value) = 1`

`4| 4 (array1 4th value) + 0 (array2 4th value) = 4`

**Another example (different cells):**

`1| array1`

`2| array2`

this would return=

`1| 1 (array1 1st value) = 1 (there is no other array value there so nothing else is added)`

`2| 2 (array1 2nd value) + 0 (array2 1st value) = 2`

`3| 0 (arra1 3rd value) + 0 (array2 2rd value) = 0 4|`

`4 (array1 4th value) + 1 (array2 3rd value) = 5`

`5| 0 (array2 4th value) = 0`

**Third example:**

`1| array1 + array3`

`2|`

`3| array2`

this returns=

`1| 1 (arr1 1st) + 0 (arr3 1st) = 1`

`2| 2 (arr1 2nd) + 1 (arr3 2nd) = 3`

`3| 0 (arr1 3rd) + 6 (arr3 3rd) + 0 (arr2 1st) = 6`

`4| 4 (arr1 4th) + 2 (arr3 4th) + 0 (arr2 2nd) = 6`

`5| 1 (arr2 3rd) = 1 6| 0 (arr2 (4th) = 0`

Notes: the arrays aren't limited to 4 values, it depends on my database and they go up to 26 cells (1 per value for each array name). I reduced them to 4 for this example only.
My database is static though, so you don't need to worry about array2 becoming something else mid calculations. If array2 is "a b c d" it will be that until the end.

**Some ways to interpret this**

So in other words I want to treat them as arrays that would have overlapped otherwise, but keep adding the values.
Another way to see it is imagine REF errors didn't exist due to overlapping a cell, and it just kept going.
You could fix this by adding more auxiliary columns and adding values on separate columns to make sure they don't overlap, but you would need a ridiculous amount of columns for this and we already tried it, it went horribly wrong.
I know this request might not be clear so I'll reply to anyone that tries to help, other people struggled with this in the past and if I'm here it's because it's my last resort before giving up.

I have tried asking in the sheets Discord and I got told to come here many times to be fair but every new person that got involved with this found a new approach but we never managed to solve it.
I ended up receiving a script that does this and it does the job but it's extremely slow. Even if you help me fix the script instead, I need to solve this for multiple formulas, as my sheet depends on this several times.
Having that script run on edit was horrible for its performance.

I'm going to be posting here the script that does the job ONLY because I think it could help you understand the issue and NOT because I'm trying to fix the script. I'm trying to get rid of it.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFi9U.png)

Here "abilities" would be that column where I typed array1 + array3, etc., and "database" is the whole array that contains both the array name and its respective values.

Once again, the way the database is setup is:

`name1 | value1 | value2 | ... | valueN`

`:`

`. nameN | value1 | value2 | ... | valueN`

Obviously the values are different for every array (or "name") that exists, but I have them stored. So for testing purposes you could just set a simple database with random names and values.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yctnP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a potential solution. It extends through an amount of rows equal to the last column of your sheet plus the last value found in column A for the names of arrays, so you're sure everything is taken:

```
COLUMNS(B1:1)+INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))-ROW()
```

With BYROW and SEQUENCE, you'll have a SUM of the MAPped cells through the values, having the position with MATCH of each of the arrays names.

I've created up to five arrays, with more decimals in each case so you can easily see what values are taken in each opportunity.

```
=BYROW(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:1)+INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))-ROW()),
LAMBDA(each,SUM(
  MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(arr,IFNA(IF(MATCH("*"&arr&"*",A7:A,0)<=each,IFERROR(INDEX(B1:5,ROW(arr),each-MATCH("*"&arr&"*",A7:A,0)+1)))))))))
```

[image]

Other setup:

[image]

Let me know!

---

### UPDATE:

With the possibility of starting arrays again you can use:

```
=BYROW(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:1)+INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))-ROW()),
LAMBDA(each,SUM(MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(arr,IFNA(IFERROR(INDEX(B1:5,ROW(arr),each+row()-XLOOKUP(1,INDEX(--REGEXMATCH(A7:INDEX(A7:A,each),arr)),INDEX(ROW(A7:INDEX(A7:A,each))),-90,0,-1)))))))))
```

[image]

---

### RE-UPDATE

For avoiding similar matching values, you can use this formula. Always separate with the same character, "+" in my formula, or change it accordingly:

```
=BYROW(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:1)+INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))-ROW()),
LAMBDA(each,SUM(MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(arr,IFNA(IFERROR(INDEX(B1:5,ROW(arr),each+row()-XLOOKUP(1,BYROW(A7:INDEX(A7:A,each),LAMBDA(v,IF(IFERROR(MATCH(arr,TRIM(SPLIT(v,"+")),0),)>0,1,0))),INDEX(ROW(A7:INDEX(A7:A,each))),-90,0,-1)))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: You can change both times number 5 appears to narrow or widen the amount of arrays

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response. I wasn't expecting it to be fair. So I tried this same setup and it worked, but adding anything else to the green part doesn't add anything else. So if I typed array1 again it wouldnt add it. I think it's because the array was already used before, because if I add a new array to the database, and then use it, it will be added.

Comment: Ahhh, it would overlap over itself?? Meaning you could start array1 before it ends the previous sequence?

Comment: No but at some point during that column I might use it again. To be clear, this is part of a game design, where you can use something called abilities (in our case, arrayN) and you can only use them when their cooldown is over. that means the same array could appear once in that column or 20 times depending on your needs. It wont overlap itself though, meaning that I won't be able to use "array1" while it's still happening. Here you have a pic as an [example](https://imgur.com/a/6nVt8DO) where the first column is my input, 2nd column is expected and 3rd is your formula

Comment: Try new update at the bottom of the answer!

Comment: Amazing! These new functions are incredibly powerful. Is it fine if I keep this open for a few days to give it proper testing? I ran it with my data and multiple examples and they all worked, but I dont want to close it in case I'm missing something. I won't fully know if it works until I'm done. It's looking really bright right now though, thank you!!!

Comment: Hey before continuing thanks again this has been greater progress :) and I'm getting a message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?", should I hit that? because I found another issue

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I can't launch it

Comment: Apparently my reputation is not high enough whoops. Well this should be the last issue hopefully, as everything else is working. I noticed that if I have 2 arrays with similar names it loads both at the same time. For example (I'll just give you the names I use on the main sheet): "assault" and "assault 2hit". if I use assault 2hit it will load both at the same time, instead of just the one I input. I have many of these entries on my database for different array names so it will happen constantly. Could this be fixed?

Comment: If you're consistent with the way you separate your values in each row when there's more than one. Meaning separated by "+" like in your example, you can use the new update

Comment: It works! However, I'm getting this error "Error
Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula" when my range for the index is too big (data is 284 rows long). It worked with a sample of 10 rows though. I think the last part you added caused that. A band-aid fix I can think of is changing all names so they arent the same so the new part wouldnt be needed.

Comment: The ones that are causing troubles are the ones that have the only word like "assault", just by changing anything in those it will work. Adding a number, changing to capital letters, some symbol, etc. If I can think of another approach, I'll let you know!

Comment: Try this variation of the previous formula with more REGEXMATCH options. It requires to have a space and + symbol to separate. For example, "array1 + array2" - =BYROW(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:1)+INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))-ROW()), LAMBDA(each,SUM(MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(arr,IFNA(IFERROR(INDEX(B1:5,ROW(arr),each+row()-XLOOKUP(1, INDEX(--REGEXMATCH(A7:INDEX(A7:A,each),"^"&arr&" +|^"&arr&"$|\+ "&arr&"$")),INDEX(ROW(A7:INDEX(A7:A,each))),-90,0,-1)))))))))

Comment: Hey, I'm bringing bad news. I tried this on a blank sheet with 100 rows of data and the formula lags really bad and can't do any edits. I tried it on my main sheet and it was unusable too. I tried converting this into a custom function but that didn't help. All the formulas you gave me have gone through the same. I don't want to make you lose your time any longer so we can leave it here. I've seen way longer lambda functions that work perfectly fine so I don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Solution presented by the Spreadsheets Discord (Astral):

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(keys,values,queries,lambda(lastrow,reduce(if(sequence(lastrow+columns(values)-1),),sequence(lastrow),lambda(a,c,byrow({a,transpose(split(transpose(iferror(rept("",c-1)&bycol(split(index(range,c)," +"),lambda(x,join("",filter(values,keys=x))))&rept("",lastrow-c),rept("",lastrow+columns(values)-2))),"",,))},lambda(x,sum(x))))))(max(if(queries="",,row(queries)))-row()+1))(names,damage,range))
```

names (range of array names)

damage (range of array values)

range (where you type "array1 + array2")

It has a few issues but they can all be solved with some auxiliary columns.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello! I haven0t seen your answer before! If you want to take a look, I've created a new option with two differences: two columns for inserting  arrays instead of + sign, and a cell that calculates maximum cell. Up to 1500 rows it just take a couple of sceonds. Good luck!  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cAjo6LUCTjbPWmCcnxsPUcCsFbDIx_SkfVFo33Q4OTE/edit?usp=sharing